# How to store values from for loop in array using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I just wanted to get all the values from the loop in a single array variable `details` which is declared outside the loop. But, I didn't get it wot work. How do I do this?

```
var details = [];
for(i=0;i<taskArray.length;i++){
    details = taskArray[i].concat("-",stateArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just do `details.push(taskArray[i])`

Answer (score 0):

Just simple you can make use array push method, you can push items one by one, as like as below:

```
function cancatTaskState(taskArray,stateArray){
    var details = [];
    for(i=0;i<taskArray.length;i++){
        details.push(taskArray[i].concat("-",stateArray[i]));
    } 
    return details;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. it works :) any idea about "org.mozilla.javascript.NativeArray@e4e213" error ? when i pass the result through web service,it shows like this.

Comment: Welcome priya...:)am not sure about java, how to pass value in web services. But this link has solution for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433382/how-to-convert-rhino-javascript-arrays-to-java-arrays